# It there difference between `sys.exit()` and `sys.exit(_())`

Tags: python, sys

I am aware of some facts about `sys.exit()`. However, I have seen some usage of `sys.exit(_("some error msg blablabla"))`, is there any differences between them?

Comment: *Where* have you seen that? Is in in something using `_` for i18n (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/3001761, #2)? Have you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit?

Comment: I have read the official doc, the stackoverflow post is useful, thx.

Answer (score 0):

One would be use to exit out and display a message on the console, so if you are for example running a game and let's say you have a menu:

Option 1 - Play
Option 2 - Options
Option 3 - Exit

If the user selects option 3 you could then call sys.exit() but what if you wanted to show a nice message to engage them say sys.exit('Thank you for playing I hope you come back soon') basically that will be displayed after the player selects option 3.

Comment: If you pass a string (or anything other than an `int` or `None`), then `sys.exit` will set the system exit status to 1 (failure).  So you wouldn't use it to show “a nice message”, but you could use it to display an error message explaining why you're exiting the program.

Comment: if you pass the value of 0 which is an integer then is considered “successful termination” so you can show a nice message, and yes anything other than that will be a failure.